# How to rawurldecode in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty

I have some hrefs in my Smarty template which contains rawurlencoded chars. How can I rawurldecocde them in Smarty ?
Here is small annotation to the post:

**Php part:**

```
"manufacturerName"=>rawurlencode($row["manufacturerName"])
```

**Template part**

```
<a href="blablabla?brand={$_manufacturer.manufacturerName}">{$_manufacturer.manufacturerName}</a>
```

I tried use Smarty's |escape build-in function but didn't find work solution.

Comment: You could pass both the encoded and decoded versions from PHP and use them separately i.e. `$_manufacturer.manufacturerNameEncoded` and `$_manufacturer.manufacturerNameDecoded`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smarty provides the `escape/unescape` functions for the encode and decode functionality

```
{$_manufacturer.manufacturerName|unescape:"htmlall"}
```

Here is the offical documentation for [unescape](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.unescape.tpl) / [escape](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.escape.tpl)